# ld.exe cannot find -lcurl

Tags: c++, mingw, libcurl, linker-errors, codeblocks

(I spotted a question similar to this, but it was 2 years old.)

I'm developing a Windows Form Application in Visual C++ 2008, which uses the FTP feature of libCurl.  Although I've added the lib and include directories to the include and library search paths, added libcurl_imp.lib to Additional Dependencies and added CURL_STATICLIB to the Preproccessor Definitions, I get 14 linker errors when I build it.  I checked the cURL FAQ and Google'd some of the errors, but I've yet to find a solution.  The linker errors are as follows:

```
1>-------.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z); calling convention missing in metadata
1>-------.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z); calling convention missing in metadata
1>-------.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ); calling convention missing in metadata
1>-------.obj : error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ); calling convention missing in metadata
1>-------.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000E) "extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000F) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000010) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000011) "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000012) "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __clrcall curl_easy_cleanup(void *)" (?curl_easy_cleanup@@$$J0YMXPAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_perform(void *)" (?curl_easy_perform@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAX@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" enum CURLcode __clrcall curl_easy_setopt(void *,enum CURLoption,...)" (?curl_easy_setopt@@$$J0YM?AW4CURLcode@@PAXW4CURLoption@@ZZ)
1>-------.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __clrcall curl_easy_init(void)" (?curl_easy_init@@$$J0YMPAXXZ) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)
```

(I blanked out the project name.)

What's causing this, how can I prevent it?  Thanks :)

---

*UPDATE*

I've switched to Code::Blocks and now its a native Win32 GUI App.  I don't get all those linker errors, but I do get something:

```
ld.exe cannot find -lcurl.lib
```

Instead of adding the include and lib directories to the search directories, I just put them in my project directory.  I am confused by this error because the name of the lib is libcurl.lib, and not curl.lib.  Any ideas on what has happened?

EDIT: sorry for all the edits, I just wanted to mention that I added libcurl.lib to the Link Libraries.

---

*UPDATE*

Now I've added -lcurl to the Other Link Options box, the error has changed to

```
ld.exe cannot find -lcurl
```

without the .lib part.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the libs are in the library search path of the compiler and that the library is compiled for the same architecture as your executable (32 vs 64 bit, single vs multi threaded).

Comment: The only lib file is libcurl.lib, and that's in the projects folder. Adding the project folder to the linker search paths didn't do anything. It's definately 32 bit, I'm not sure about the single and multi threaded part though.